# Limit access to Jenkins web dashboard

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, jenkins

At the moment I'm running Jenkins on my Mac Mini and everybody in my local network can access the web dashboard at the address `http://<JenkisIP>:8080`. How can I setup username and password credentials to limit the access to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to check the enable security feature in the configure menu, select "Jenkins's own user database" as the security realm and then alter the security matrix to suit your requirements.

For the first run, give everyone full access. Allow users to sign up, create your own account (if you don't have one) and then give full privileges to that account and remove all privileges to anonymous.

All the information you need should be found here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup